# Android native browser does not support JavaScript Regexp .match()?

Tags: javascript, android, regex

The following code doesn't seem to work fine on an android native web browser nor on Dolphin App.

```
"[1212,1212],[1212,11212]".match(/\d+,\d+/g)
```

When I alert this statement, it says "undefined"

Comment: Is your question "Does Android's native browser support `.match()`?" Or are you asking for a workaround, or...?

Comment: Yea, does android support regex in javascript? If it does not support, then what is the work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.match(regEx)` is not supported by most of mobile browsers.

Try `String.split(",")` instead

```
[1212,1212],[1212,11212]".split(",") returns an array : [ "[1212,1212]", "[1212,11212]" ]
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.